# Unable to connect to my local MySql database using npm.mysql. Getting 6 different errors such as crypto, resolve, stream, timers, fs

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, typescript

Well as stated above I am trying fetch data from my local database in mySql but I am getting differnet errors saying I need to install different modules. I have tried a lot of possible solution including, installing the npm packages of the different modules that it says it can't find. I have also tried to configure them to falls in my webpack, but nothing works.

my provider class is very simple with the following code:

```
import mysql from 'mysql';

export default interface IDrink {
  id: number;
  price: number;
  size: string;
  brand: string;
}

export class DrinksProvider {

  constructor() {

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      database: "databaseTest"
    });

    connection.connect((err: mysql.MysqlError) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("connected!")
    })
  }
}
```

Some of the error I get is as follows:
[image]